# Multinomial logit coefficient interpretation confusion

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients, multinomial-distribution, logit

In my lecture slides two different ways of interpreting coefficients for the multinomial logit model are discussed. However, numerical values differ and I don't see how they are related. Could anyone please tell me how they are related and why they are different [I understand that option 1 is an approximation, but the difference with option seems rather large]?

---

**Option 1**: interpret the log odds directly and make use of the fact that for a log dependent variable it holds that the coefficient can be interpreted as an x*100% increase.

The log odds of being in the medium program vs. in the difficult program will increase
by 1.163 if moving from effort=“high” to effort=“low”. In
other words, it leads to
probability of being in the medium program being lower by 116.3%, relative to the probability of being in the difficult program.

**Option 2**: exponentiate the coefficients before interpreting

The relative risk ratio for switching from effort = high to low is 3.2 for being in medium program vs. difficult program (base). In other words, switching from effort = high to low leads to the relative risk of the being in medium program (compared to being in the difficult program) being multiplied by 3.2.